# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: machine-learning, python, machine-learning-model, image-segmentation

I'm building an OCR to read text off of water meters. I'm running into the error mentioned above when I try to fit the machine learning model. I am using the [segmentation_models](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models) python library.

```
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)



x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = train_test_split(X,y, test_size = 0.2, random_state= 12345)


x_train = preprocess_input(x_train)
x_val = preprocess_input(x_val)

model = sm.Unet(BACKBONE, encoder_weights='imagenet', encoder_freeze=True)
model.compile('Adam', 
   loss=sm.losses.bce_jaccard_loss,
   metrics=[sm.metrics.iou_score])

model.fit(
   x = x_train,
   y = y_train,
   batch_size=16,
   epochs=10,
   validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

'X' represents the images and 'y' represents the masks; both have 1244 images.

The full error:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 995
y sizes: 249
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.enter code here
```

Please let me know if I need to post more info. I don't use this platform often.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the fact that you are using the `train_test_split` incorrectly. The function returns the arrays in the following order: `arr1_train`, `arr1_test`, `arr2_train`, `arr2_test` etc. This means that in your example you are assigning the values of your `X_train` dataset to the `y_train` variable and using it as if they contain the label info. The correct way of using the `train_test_split` function is to change the order of the variable names in line with [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

```
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state= 12345)
```